# GeckoFX (C#) - Programmatically login to SharePoint (NTLM)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, geckofx

I am currently attempting to use GeckoFx version 33 to automatically login to a SharePoint 2010 instance. I have attempted to following the suggestions from this [post](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-14.0/issues/19/promptservice-not-working) without much luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might search for how to enable NTLM authenticaiton in Firefox. The same steps should work in GeckoFX.

This SuperUser question seems to cover enabling the relevant features in Firefox:
https://superuser.com/questions/664656/how-to-configure-firefox-for-ntlm-sso-single-sign-on

It seems that you need to add the relevant URIs to the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` property.

Of course you'll need to do this programatically. For example:

```
string intranet_domains = @"my_intranet_domain.com, my_other_intranet_domain.com";
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris") = intranet_domains;
```